# PHP sortby statement using images

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, filter

With a current project I am working on, I am trying to do a PHP orderby statement. But instead of using a select list, I want to use images as a filter key. For some reason it is not working at all and I am very confused: Here is the code

```
$ordercol = "jtype";
 if(isset($_POST['sortchoice'])){
 $ordercol = $_POST['sortchoice'];
}

<form action="jobs.php" method="post" id="sortform">
<div class="list" name="sortchoice" onchange="document.getElementById('sortform').submit();">
    <a><img src="img/key-graphics.png" value="jtype"></a>
    <a><img src="img/key-web.png" value="jtype"></a>
    <a><img src="img/key-video.png" value="jtype"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any PHP ordering anywhere in your post.  Please include the code you wish to have help with in the question

Comment: @Ray, Agreed. The title of this post is misleading and irrelevant to what has actually been posted in the body. I suggest OP edit's the title to something that actually fits what they are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

`div`'s and `a`'s are not form tags.

Use the `<input type="image" />` instead.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['jtype-graphics'])) {
    $ordercol = 'graphics';
}

if(isset($_POST['jtype-web'])) {
    $ordercol = 'web';
}

if(isset($_POST['jtype-video'])) {
    $ordercol = 'video';
}

?>

<form action="jobs.php" method="post" id="sortform">

    <div class="list">
        <input type="image" src="img/key-graphics.png" name="jtype-graphics" />
        <input type="image" src="img/key-web.png" name="jtype-web" />
        <input type="image" src="img/key-video.png" name="jtype-video" />
    </div>

</form>
```

This is pretty basic HTML stuff. you should probably do some research... http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

This is a decent starting point for learning.

Comment: Wow, you've got some mad translation skills to scry what the question was asking for...

Comment: @Ray haha, yeah I can see what OP is attempting, but OP needs to do some reading on HTML methinks...

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I get this is "easy stuff", but I don't work with this on a constant basis so take it easy on me. I get this is easily researched but I'm using this website to get helpful input, not to be criticized for a skill that I am not fluent in like you. And the sorting part of this does not work how I want it to still so..

Comment: Before you get defensive about me providing a link to more information about what you are trying to do you need to understand that when you post HTML that is completely wrong it is highly evident that you have not done research. We are here to help ( I mean that is the point of this site) but you need to play your part in this community too and respect that doing research before you post is paramount of what all this is about. We aren't here to belittle you for not knowing what we do, so please take some constructive criticism when it is handed out.